# Issue in Elementor stacking containers with parallax effects

Tags: wordpress, parallax, vertical-scrolling

Created Stacked Containers with motion effects to look like parallax effect in elementor pro and used dot navigation for reaching containers. the thing is I cant scroll to previously visited containers.

I tried with different pluggins and html/css integration for making that possible